# Scala - Sum of positive Ints being negative - Overflow Exception?

Tags: scala, exception, integer, overflow

I just had a hard time finding a bug which was being caused due to a large sum of positive ints being greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

My question is:
why:

```
val a:Int = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 2
```

`-> a = -2147483648` returns a negative number, as opposed as giving an overflow exception like doing:

```
val b:Int =999999999999999999
```

`-> error: integer number too large`

Why is not throwing an exception the standard?

Comment: because first done by Scala and another by you

Comment: The important point here is that the error you see in the `val b` case isn't an exception—it happens at compile-time, not runtime. Having the compiler reject invalid literals is cheap, runtime checking for overflows is expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding checks costs performance and some code could rely on how overflows work.

If you don't want an overflow Java 8 has a solution:

```
Math.addExact(left, right);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int-

Comment: Interesting! I am currently working with java 7 but I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: performance.

Long answer:

The basic "binary" system doesn't have anything built in to represent negative numbers, it consists of only 0's and 1's.  The question is: how do we represent negative numbers using only 0's and 1's?

The standard answer is to use the two's-complement format. A simple example for a 3-bit binary system: 000 means 0, 011 means 3, 111 means -1 (makes sense as when you substract 1 from 0, you want -1), 100 means -3.  If you add 1 to 011 or 3, you get 111 or -3.

Now, why doesn't that cause an overflow exception?  Two reasons:

1. Exception itself is a relatively new concept and it was too late to change the binary system the computing hardware world uses.
2. Condition checking and throwing exception is an overhead that has a performance cost. If we want high performance, these are often unnecessary.  There is performance gain if there is no explicit checking done for any overflow exception.

Comment: I knew the operation that generated the negative number. Also It is good to understand why the check is not taking place, thanks :).